# How to solve a recurrence when the master theorem fails?

Tags: recurrence-relation

How do solve the following recurrence?

> $$ T(n) = \frac{1}{2} T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{n}. $$

Master's theorem cannot be applied as $a$ is equal to 0.5 which is less than 1. Hence the theorem fails. How do I solve a recurrence when the theorem fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly unroll the recursion:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2} T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\ &=
\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{4} T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) \\ &= \cdots \\ &=
\frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{2^m} T \left(\frac{n}{2^m}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
This easily leads to the solution
$$T(n) = \frac{\log_2 n + T(1)}{n},$$
which is valid for powers of 2.